# More elegant ways of converting YES/NO to true/false

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

There might be a very basic thing that might be missing. Please let me know 
if there is a better way to do this which is much more elegant than using the ternary operator in javascript.

```
if (data.isYellowCupcake === YES) {
  dataCopy.isCupcake = true;
} else if (data.isYellowCupcake === NO) {
  dataCopy.isCupcake = false;
}
```

Comment: Ternary operator seems very short and elegant for this solution, unless you have more cases besides `YES == true`, otherwise `false`

Comment: What are the values of `YES` and `NO` variables?

Comment: Ternary would be elegant i guess. The real question is why does this data have a bad format? isYellowCupcake should be a boolean to begin with. Or even better, data.color = 'yellow' would even be preferred so that you do not need a property for each existing color of cupcake.

Comment: @Cray yes it has more cases than that the thing is isCupkake should be set if only isYellowCupkake has either YES or NO. it should not be set if the data.isYellowCupkake value is not set.

Comment: @Teemu those are just a string constants that have 'yes' or 'no'

Comment: @Shilly we have a component in react that will ask user a question that will let them select a YES/NO radio button. Well.. the variable name are just an example.. it has nothing to do with cupcakes nor the color. Sorry if those names are miss leading.

Comment: You can have [more than 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#Conditional_chains) options in ternary operator. I posted example below.

Comment: So you can just change the react state and render() function to use booleans and change the value behind the radio buttons to 1 and 0 instead of yes and no to prevent the problem to begin with? Then you can use null in the state as the default value and hence only clicking a radio will toggle null to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
dataCopy.isCupkake = data.isYellowCupkake === YES;
```

By the way, the word cupcake only has one `k`.

Comment: That works well, but the thing is `isCupkake` should be set if only `isYellowCupkake ` has either `YES` or `NO`. it should not be set if the `data.isYellowCupkake` value is not set.

Comment: @codeMan In that case `if..else` statement is the way to go. Don't try to compress developement code, the compressor does it for you when you're compressing the code for production.

Comment: @codeMan: in that case I think its bad wording to call the property isYellowCupkake. The is-prefix implies only two states. It is also difficult advising for a good solution without the greater context of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you said you don't want ternary operator I will leave this here.

```
   dataCopy.isCupcake = data.isYellowCupcake === 'YES' ? true 
    : data.isYellowCupcake === 'NO' ? false 
    : null;
```